# Is there a max packet size in Silverlight Polling Duplex?

Tags: silverlight, size, max, packet, pollingduplexhttpbinding

Is there a max packet size in Silverlight Polling Duplex? My client code -which just simply prints the item count of the pushed list to a label- does work for 500 items in list but does noting (not event hitting the breakpoint in PushReveived event) for 1000 items. I checked the packet sizes in Firebug, 500 items weight 36 KB and 1000 items weight 72 KB.

Comment: It sure looks like the default is 64k, and I have a problem if the message is more than that. If I try to raise the default by setting maxBufferSize and/or maxReceivedMessageSize="200000" for example, nothing works at all.